# cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I use dialogs in my app. But I have run to  some problems during optimizing my page for IE. In my `document.ready` function, I call this

```
$("#DFormExport").dialog({
resizable: true,
modal: false,
autoOpen: false,
width: 750
});
```

to inicialize my dialog and then when user hits the button I call this, because the type of buttons in mydialog depends on some user choice

```
$("#DFormExport").dialog("option", "buttons", {
     "Vytisknout": function () {
       loading(1);
       tiskText($("#DExportCo").attr("href"),"", $("#DExportCo").attr("rm"));
      },
      Zrušit: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
       }
}).dialog('option', 'title', 'Vytisknout');
```

In chrome and FF everything works just fine,  but in IE i am getting `cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'`

So any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have finally find a sollution. To fix the IE bug, I have just simply saved the dialog to variable during the creaion `var dialog=$("#DFormExport").dialog({...})` and then I call `dialog.dialog("option", "buttons", {....})` instead

Comment: I'm not sure it's IE related, I have similar issue in Chrome as well. I moved the site js code between projects, and after moving the dialog's part, it doesn't work as before, it shows the warning you've mentioned. I'm not sure what changed, I've made the same workaround as you.