# dialog("close") doesn't work inside ajax:success event handler

Tags: jquery, dialog, initialization

I am trying to using jQuery dialog to make a user sign in.  I am using ajax and devise. After users sign in, the dialog windows should close. I put dialog("close") inside bind("ajax:success"), but it doesn't work and I get error:

`"cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempt  to call method 'close'"`

**Code:**

```
$(function(){
$(" #sign_in").click(function(){
     $('<div id="box" >').dialog({
        open: function(){ 
                 var that=this;
                 $(this).load("/users/sign_in",function(){ 
                    $("#new_user").bind("ajax:success",function(evt,data,status,xhr){
                    $("div#utility").html('welcome'+data.user+' |<a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">sign out</a> ') ;
                    $(that).dialog('close');
                      })
               })
             },
        title: 'Sign in '
        });
   });
})
```

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is?
 thanks

Comment: can you clean that up a bit instead of it being a jumbled mess, please?

Comment: thank Tomcat to make the code clear since I have tried but I didn't make it

Answer (score 0):

here is a question that has answers that might help with your problem.

[jQuery: Load Modal Dialog Contents via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837166/jquery-load-modal-dialog-contents-via-ajax)

you can also change your selector for the dialog to `$('#box').dialog({ ...`

and in your ajax success callback (after you make changes) you can do `$('#box').dialog('close')`

EDIT:
this work?

```
$(function(){
$(" #sign_in").click(function(){
 $('#box').dialog({
    open: function(){ 
        $(this).load("/users/sign_in");
    },
    title: 'Sign in '
    });
});

$("#new_user").bind("ajax:success",function(evt,data,status,xhr){
    $("div#utility").html('welcome'+data.user+' |<a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">sign out</a> ') ;
    $('#box').dialog('close');
   })
})
```

Comment: thanks ajgiv, I have tried using $('#box').dialog('close') and I have tried $('<div id="box">').load(...).dialog(). but I always meet the error 'cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization'. the problem is when I want to close the dialog, it already there.

Comment: are you doing an ajax request somewhere for the sign in/sign up portion?

Comment: yes, I load page from /users/new, I use devise. every thing works fine but the dialog cannot be closed after sign in. I can close the dialog by clicking the close button.

Comment: I got solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626675/cannot-call-methods-on-dialog-prior-to-initialization-attempted-to-call-method and it really works